# Склейка include-файлов, если файлы лежат в разных директориях

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте, в `PHP` я новичок - только учусь. Не могли бы вы мне подсказать, как заставить работать `include`-файлы, если сами страницы лежат в разных директориях?

Пример:
Есть сервер, страничка клеится с помощью

```
include ('header.php');
include ('footer.php');
```

На сайте уже получается очень много разных страничек и надо их поместить в отдельную папку `pages`, но при переносе в эту папку страницы перестают склеиваться, поскольку файлы `header.php` и `footer.php` лежат в корневой директории.

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы странички также нормально склеивались?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант назначить корневую директорию

```
define('BASE_PATH',$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
```

и использовать её для установки путей к файлам.

Для примера BASE_PATH будет установлен - /home/user/site/www - это корень Вашего сайта. 
Файл header.php лежит в директории inc, а файл footer.php лежит в директории data. Тогда подключать их будем таким образом:

```
include BASE_PATH.'/inc/header.php';
include BASE_PATH.'/data/footer.php';
```

Для указания файлов в include не обязательно использовать скобки, достаточно кавычек.
Также почитайте про разницу между include и  require . Если подключение файлов находится в конструкции if else лучше использовать require.

Answer (score 0):

я незнаю как некоторые но я пишу просто без ()

**

```
include "header.php";
include "papka/page.php";
include "footer.php";
```

**

у меня бы выглядело это так.

Comment: если в корневой а нужна папка выше то include "../header.php";

Comment: @big-vl, как раз необходимо наоборот, файл находится не в корневой, а файлы footer.php и header.php в корневой. И в итоге ничего не склеивается в виду того что он не может увидеть файлы в корневой директории, поскольку для него корневой директорией является та в которой лежит файл about_us.php то есть pages/about_us.php

Comment: надо `dirname(dirname(__FILE__))` юзать чтобы указать на предыдущую директорию. типа

index.php:

    <?php include "includes/myinclude.php";

includes/myinclude.php: 

    <?php include dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."header.php";

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте как работает include:

Выражение include() включает и выполняет указанный файл.

Файлы включаются исходя из пути указанного файла, или, если путь не указан, используется путь, указанный в директиве include_path. Если файл не найден в include_path, include() попытается проверить директорию, в которой находится текущий включающий скрипт и текущую рабочую директорию перед тем, как выдать ошибку. Конструкция include() выдаст warning, если не сможет найти файл; поведение отлично от require(), который выдаст фатальную ошибку.

Если путь указан — не важно, абсолютный (начинающийся с буквы диска или с \ в Windows или с / в Unix/Linux системах) или относительно текущей директории (начинающийся с . или ..) — директива include_path будет проигнорирована в любом случае. К примеру, если начинается с ../, парсер проверит родительскую директорию на наличие запрошенного файла.

Для большей информации о том, как PHP обрабатывает включаемые файлы и включаемые пути, смотрите документацию для директивы include_path.

Когда файл включается, его код наследует ту же область видимости переменых, что и строка, на которой произошло включение. Все переменные, доступные на этой строке во включащем файле будут также доступны во включаемом файле. Однако все функции и классы, объявленные во включаемом файле, будут доступны в глобальной области видимости.

Источник http://php.ru/manual/function.include.html